# How does polymorphism work for inner classes?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding, inner-classes

When I tried to understand how to work with collections in java, I realised that I don't understand how polymorphism works for inner classes.

Simple code example:

```
 class Parent {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Parent().newInnerClass().myMethod();
        new Child().newInnerClass().myMethod();
    }

    public I newInnerClass() {
        return new InnerClass();
    }

    private final class InnerClass implements I {

        @Override
        public void myMethod() {
            System.out.println("parent inner class");
            foo();
        }
    }

    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("foo from parent");
    }


}

class Child extends Parent {
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("foo from child");
    }
}

interface I {
    void myMethod();
}
```

result:

```
parent inner class
foo from parent
parent inner class
foo from child
```

Therefore first link affects the third method invocation. It is surprising to me.

Initially I thought that needed methods selected accordind to the link. But `new Parent().newInnerClass()` and `new Child().newInnerClass()` are links to `InnerClass` from `Parent`.

Can you clarify my misunderstanding?

### P.S.

If `InnerClass` was in Child and extended `InnerClass` from `Parent` - this behaviour wouldn't be surprising for me.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're surprised that `parent...` is printed the second time? I really didn't follow

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ I expected to see "foo from parent" 2 times

Comment: You don't since the second time the child has its own `foo`. You probably got that, but I still don't understand the confusion.

Comment: InnerClass  - class from Parent. Inner class doesn't know anything about Child

Comment: If InnerClass was in Child and extends InnerClass from Parent - it wouldn't surprise.

Comment: InnerClass definitely does know about Child, if it's created from a Child.  As you saw it printed "foo from child".

Comment: Now I get it :) Well it seems as if you could view it as the inner class being "copied" to Child.

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ Yes it looks so. But it strange for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no special rules for polymorphism in inner classes.

Inner class differs from regular class in two things:

- Inner class holds an implicit reference to its containing object
- Inner class can access `private` methods of its containing class (not relevant here)

That's how you can rewrite your example without inner class:

```
class Parent {
    ...
    public I newInnerClass() {
        return new NotInnerClass(this);
    }
    ...
}
class NotInnerClass implements I {
    private final Parent containingObject;

    public NotInnerClass(Parent containingObject) {
        this.containingObject = containingObject;
    }

    @Override
    public void myMethod() {
        System.out.println("parent inner class");
        containingObject.foo();
    }
}
```

This code produces the same output as your, because when you invoke

```
new Child().newInnerClass().myMethod();
```

`containingObject` is a `Child` and `containingObject.foo()` is a regular polymorphic call.

When you use inner class, compiler does the same thing behind the scenes.

Comment: Can you provide main method for your example?

Comment: Can you clarify this quote: **containingObject is a Child**

Comment: `main()` method is the same as yours. Do you understand how polymorphism works in general?

Comment: yes, of course. needed methods determines by type of object(not by link type)

Comment: should I write **new Parent().newInnerClass().myMethod();** in main ?

Comment: I didn't notice  that you pass **this** in constructor

Comment: Thus if  I pass new Child there - I get another result.

Comment: What's the problem? My example produces different output?